# Python input to callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make this work:

```
recognized = input("COMMAND: ")
if recognized == "command":
co = input("Input: ")
co()
```

Which gives me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: What do you expect the result of `co()` to be (and for what input)?

Comment: Can you give an example of expected input/output?

Comment: you're trying to say that a string is a function when it clearly isn't

Comment: Are you wanting to print it? Then `print(co)` should suffice, otherwise `return co`.

Comment: this is what we want to avoid. Guessing what he wants until we get it right... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the statement in the string, you could use `exec(co)`, though this is not at all recommended. You basically are letting any code run on the system, which can be a huge security issue.

Comment: Exec will work but you have to add a `'()'` to `co` -- `exec(co+'()')` -- otherwise the function will not actually be called. Not sure why this was downvoted without comment except for the fact that people think nobody should be told about `exec`. That being said, I think my answer is probably the one to go with, especially if the application is intended for use by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you get back from `input()` is a string. You can call a locally-defined function using

```
locals()['my_function']()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  In context, the example code would be `locals()[co]()`

Answer (score -1):

To define a function use `def`

```
def inputFunc():
    return input("input: ")

co = inputFunk()
```

This gives the variable `co` a value of whatever you inputed.

or just use this if you want to print the input instead of calling it.

```
co = input("Input: ")
print(co)
```

This prints your input.

Comment: This doesn't do what they want -- they don't want a function named `co`, they want to call a function whose string name is stored in `co`.

Comment: @MoxieBall Understood and I edited my answer. Have a look now?

Comment: The things in this answer are all true, however they are irrelevant to the question which is asking how to call a function by its string name.

Answer (score -1):

Use `eval` function

```
co = input()
eval(co)
```

Also a little trick I like to use, when I want multiple inputs to be evaluated or to be done something with them, is

```
s = input()
while s != 'the end': ## here you should use something that can't occur 
                      ## in python itself in form of function or variable etc.

    ## here come things you want to do with s, e.g. print(eval(s))
    s = input()
```

Comment: This should also come with a warning similar to the one included with the answer referencing `exec`